# Electron not getting command line arguments

Tags: electron

Trying to make an option for localhost dev in Electron.js (I have two types of config.inis for local and not-local options) and would like to run command from command line, e.g yarn dev --scope=local

However, I am not able to get process.argv to work, argv array shows only:

[
'C:\xxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\node_modules\electron\dist\electron.exe',
'-r',
'./internals/scripts/BabelRegister',
'./app/main.dev.ts'
]

Here it says that getting argv depends on the process type, but mine is main. [Passing command line arguments to electron executable (after installing an already packaged app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552703/passing-command-line-arguments-to-electron-executable-after-installing-an-alrea)

Would appreciate help!